# Problems with plt.show(), no errors returned yet no image shows

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I'm executing below code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
imgL = cv.imread('tsukuba_l.png', 0)
imgR = cv.imread('tsukuba_r.png', 0)

stereo = cv.StereoBM(1, 16, 15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)

plt.imshow(disparity, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

there are no errors being returned, yet no image is showing up, ive tried reinstalling matplotlib but that didn't help

Comment: Your code fails in `stereo.compute()` with exitcode `0xC0000005`. I'm not sure if it will give the same result but `stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(16, 15)` worked well.

Comment: Hmm it seems that it returns an error when changed, i paste it below:                                                                                                              'error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) SADWindowSize must be odd, be within 5..255 and be not larger than image width or height in function ''cv::StereoBMImpl::compute'

Comment: Now you have something concrete to google. Try this: https://answers.opencv.org/question/185947/how-to-resolve-a-sadwindowsize-error/

Comment: Yeah i've been on that thread; i don't know how to use advice given in this thread to be honest, i have no idea where to put the line given by person responding

Comment: Check if paths to your tsukuba images are correct. I have no problem with this code but I'm getting your error if I specify an invalid path to `imread()`.

Comment: Yes, it seems something was off with the paths of imread, thank you very much :))